# Output distribution charts in a pdf format? I only need the chart from a proc univariate of all the variables in a table

Tags: sas

How can I output distribution charts in a pdf format? I only need the chart from a proc univariate of all the variables in a table - not any additional metrics.

```
ods pdf file="aaaa.pdf
TITLE 'Summary of Weight Variable (in pounds)';
PROC UNIVARIATE DATA = sashelp.class NOPRINT;
 HISTOGRAM _all_ / NORMAL;
RUN;
ods pdf close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `ODS SELECT _chartname_` to limit the output to what you want. You need to remove the `NOPRINT` option though or no output is generated to display regardless of destination.

It looks like univariate produces: CDFPlot, Histogram, PPplot, Probplot, QQplot so assuming you want just the histogram add the following line to your code:

```
ods select histogram;
```

Full code:

```
ods pdf file="aaaa.pdf;
ods select histogram;
TITLE 'Summary of Weight Variable (in pounds)';
PROC UNIVARIATE DATA = sashelp.class ;
 HISTOGRAM _all_ / NORMAL;
RUN;
ods pdf close
```

Add it before or within your PROC UNIVARIATE.

PS. You're missing a semicolon on your ODS PDF statements at the top and bottom.

A good blog post from the SAS website on this is [available here](https://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/2017/07/11/basic-ods-graphics-enabling-selecting-displaying-graphs/).